# NodeJS Sequalize - Find based on relationship

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I am using seqalize js and I have a relationship "Drivers [can have] many drivers". This is based on a Many-To-Many relationship.

I'm trying to find all of the  drivers that are based on a particular company. I have the following:

```
models.drivers.findAll({

        where: {"companies.id":1},
        include: [
          models.companies
        ]
    }).then(function(result){

        return res.json(result);
        return;

    });
```

I'm getting the following error though:

> > Unhandled rejection SequelizeDatabaseError: column drivers.companies.id does not exist

When I output the result without the `where` clause, it's showing the associated companies just fine. I can't see where this issue would come from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `where` option inside `include` according to the documentation of [`model.findAll`](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/api/model/#findalloptions-promisearrayinstance)

> Where clauses to apply to the child models.

```
models.drivers.findAll({
    include: [
        {
            model: models.companies,
            where: { id: 1 }
        }
    ]
}).then(function(result){
    return res.json(result);
});
```

This would generate `JOIN` with condition like

```sql
ON drivers.id = drivers_companies.driver_id
AND companies.id = 1
```

Assuming that `drivers_companies` is a table joining the M:M relation between `drivers` and `companies`.